# How to get Video width and height

Tags: android, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

How can i get video width and height using YouTube data API? (JAVA). For now i am able to get Video id, title.

```
    String title = videoList.get(position).getSnippet().getTitle();
String imageURL= videoList.get(position).getSnippet().getThumbnails().getDefault().getUrl();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data API doesn't have a way to retrieve any video height or width, because YouTube videos, as they're delivered, don't have inherent dimensions. Rather, the YouTube Player will dynamically scale a video based on its container size and the video resolution.

Here are some options for you, then. If you are the video's owner, you can get the dimensions of the originally uploaded video using:

```
videoList.get(position).getFileDetails().getVideoStreams()
```

which will return a list of video streams, each of which has methods such as `getHeightPixels()`, `getWidthPixels()`, `getAspectRatio()`, etc. Note that since you have to be the video's owner to get this info, the call requires oAuth2().

Another option, if you aren't the owner, would be to use YouTube's oEmbed service; an HTTP call like this:

```
http://www.youtube.com/oembed?url=http%3A//www.youtube.com/watch?v%3D-UUx10KOWIE&format=json
```

provides a default-sized embed code as well as some parameters for default width and height.

Finally, if you're actually asking for a way to get the dimensions of the thumbnails rather than the video, you could use the `getHeight()` and `getWidth()` methods of the Thumbnail object (rather than the `getUrl()` method).